# Takes too much time when i load data from Local Data Store and sometimes throws exception

Tags: android, parse-platform

Here is my code , i am using Parse , it takes too much time when i load data from Local Data Store .. aswell as when i Open my app. First time it loads but when i go back an try to open the same activity it throws exception . Please help me :(

```
try {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassName");
        List<ParseObject> objects = query.find();
        ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(objects);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception(u r offline)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1=ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassName");
        query1.fromLocalDatastore();
        query1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
            pd.dismiss();
            for(ParseObject obj : objects)
            {
                ArraylistName.add(obj.getString("PackageName"));
                ArraylistId.add(obj.getInt("Id"));
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ArraylistName);
            lv.setAdapter(ad);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Some Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Comment: post the exception too, to let us help you out.

Comment: Thanks sir i have controlled Exception . but only 1 thing left , that is when i open this activity in offline mode it stucks for some seconds and then loads data ... doesnt not throws exception .
help me out in solving this thing